# Python module not imported despite file being there

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a `python` project. I have activated `virtualenv` for it and installed `requirements.txt`

Here is my files/dirs structure

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── foo.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   └── requirements.txt
```

I am doing the following import in `foo.py`

```
import settings
```

VSCode does not complain (while in other erroneous import attempts it did complain)

[image]

When trying to run the program

```
▶ python app/app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from modules import foo
  File "/path/to/project/app/modules/foo.py", line 14, in <module>
    import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
(.venv)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to structure your project a a Python package; see Section 6.4 at [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python modules are not imported relatively out-of the box.

In `foo.py`, you can import `settings' using:

```py
from . import settings
# ...
```

@pkaramol : in older versions of python it was necessary to create `__init__.py` inside `modules` directory to be able to use this syntax, but at least in python3.10 it is not.

Comment: accepted as the correct syntax is `from . import settings`; however the `__init__.py` is no longer technically needed (perhaps this sth that was changed in `python3`? not sure about this)